# What are bit shift operators in VBA ?I am using >> and << for right and left shift respectively but it gives a compile error

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

What are bit shift operators in VBA 2013? I am using '>>' and '<<' for right and left shift respectively but I m getting a compile error. here is my function code.

```
Sub CommandButton21_Click()
  MsgBox ROTR(1, 2)
End Sub

Function ROTR(A As Integer, B As Integer) As Integer
  ROTR = A >> B
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean VBA or do yo umean VB.NET or do you mean VB-Script? Your question needs to be tagged correctly! The three are not equal! VBA does not have bit shift operators. You'd need to code the functionality yourself. There's an example at http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/496038-how-2-use-right-shift-and-left-shift-operator-in-excel.html

Comment: @CindyMeister Definitely not VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, VBA doesn't have Bitwise operators. You will have to either use VB.NET or create something on your own similar to this: http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/bit-shifting-function.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Check BITRSHIFT() or BITLSHIFT() functions which is available in 2013.